# Some SVG path properties appear to have no effect on the path

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using some javascript code to generate an SVG path. This part works perfectly. In addition, I have tried adding the following properties to this code, but none of them appear to have any effect. I don’t get any errors, but it’s as if these properties when added to the code listed below don’t have any effect at all. Can somebody please help me understand why?

1. Opacity: tried different values, e.g. 0,1, 0.5 (even values with
   percentage)
2. fillOpacity: tried different values, e.g. 0,1, 0.5 (even
   values with percentage)
3. strokeWidth: tried different values
4. strokewidth: tried different values

```
myPath = “ … ”; // path values not important

let tmpPath = r.path().attr({
    fill: "yellow",
    d: myPath,
    stroke: "green"
});
```

Comment: Please add an working example or at least a link to an working example

Comment: If you don't explain where r, path() or attr() comes from, it's hard to know what's wrong with it. if attr() is the jquery function, then it should work if path() returns a jquery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. They got me thinking and looking further. I just realized that I am using the SVG.js library for path(), so I should be using the path() attributes supported by this library. Instead of strokeWidth or strokewidth, it's just "width". I just checked and it works, though, I would have expected that I would receive some kind of error or warning if I use non-supported attributes.